# Работа с кортежами: вычисление приблизительного значения с помощью линейной интерполяции

Tags: python, массивы

Есть функция интерполяции переменной на Java:

```
public static double Interpolation(double m) {
    int k = 0;
    double x[] = {2000, 2500, 3000, 4000, 5000};
    double y[] = {0.032, 0.034, 0.040, 0.040, 0.038};
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        if (m <= x[i] && m >= x[i - 1]) {
            k = i;
        }
    double a = (y[k] - y[k - 1]) / (x[k] - x[k - 1]);
    double b = y[k - 1] - a * x[k - 1];
    return (a * m + b);
}
```

Интересует, как будет выглядеть:

```
if (m <= x[i] && m >= x[i - 1]) {
    k = i;
}
double a = (y[k] - y[k - 1]) / (x[k] - x[k - 1]);
double b = y[k - 1] - a * x[k - 1];
```

на Python.

Comment: вы хотите перевести именно эту функцию на Python или готовы воспользоваться готовыми и быстрыми функциями на Python ? Т.е. задача у вас академическая или практическая ?

Comment: Задача практическая, можно воспользоваться готовыми функциями, интересен сам подход на языке пайтон.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я бы воспользовался [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Original points
x = np.array([2000, 2500, 3000, 4000, 5000], dtype=np.float64)
y = np.array([0.032, 0.034, 0.040, 0.040, 0.038], dtype=np.float64)

# Points to interpolate
X = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 21)

# different interpolation methods (functions)
f_linear = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='linear')
f_nearest = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='nearest')
f_zero = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='zero')
f_slinear = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='slinear')  # spline interp. of 1st order
f_quadratic = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='quadratic')  # spline interp. of 2nd order
f_cubic = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')  # spline interp. of 3rd order

# plot
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 14))
# plot interpolated points
plt.plot(X, f_linear(X), '-o',
         X, f_nearest(X), '-^',
         #X, f_zero(X), '-*',
         X, f_slinear(X), '-*',
         X, f_quadratic(X), '-D',
         X, f_cubic(X), '-H',
         linewidth=1.5)
# plot original points
plt.scatter(x, y, marker='o', s=500, c='green')
plt.legend(['Linear', 'Nearest', 'Linear Spline', 'Quadratic Spline', 'Cubic Spline', 'Original points'])
plt.xlim(x.min() * 0.95, x.max() * 1.05)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Если просто переводить ваш код, то получится так:

```
def Interpolation(m):
    x = [2000, 2500, 3000, 4000, 5000]
    y = [0.032, 0.034, 0.040, 0.040, 0.038]
    for i in range(1, len(x)):
        if x[i - 1] <= m <= x[i]:
            k = i
    a = float(y[k] - y[k - 1]) / (x[k] - x[k - 1])
    b = y[k - 1] - a * x[k - 1]
    return a * m + b
```

Этот код заработает и в *Python 2* и в *Python 3*, хотя приведение типа к `float` в 3 версии не обязательно.

Ещё здесь возможна оптимизация, значительно ускоряющая код для случая большого размера массивов `x` и `y` - бинарный поиск. Также, я бы добавил проверки для `m`, на случай, если она окажется вне диапазона `x`, ведь иначе код упадёт.