# Интерполяция в SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, интерполяция

Здравствуйте. Я как начинающий пользователь столкнулся со следующей проблемой. У меня есть таблица с 3 столбцами, где у меня есть мои экспериментальные данные, которые я хотел бы отобразить на графике. Зависимость между входными данными выискивается с помощью griddata, которая ну очень медленная. Хотелось бы заменить эту интерполяцию на 2 интерполяции сплайном. Как это можно сделать?

```
>>>> bm=[1,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9, 2]
>>>> n=1/4
>>>> for j in range(1,7,1):
>>>> for i in range(0,100):
>>>> b[i]=float(bm[j]*np.sin(i*np.pi/(10)))
>>>> int=scipy.interpolate.griddata((data_1,data_2),data_3, (b[i],0.0),method='linear')
>>>> h[i]=(b[i]-float(int))*n
```

Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Comment: [Похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614537/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-python-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5)

Comment: У вас слишком общий и обширный вопрос. Попробуйте разбить его на несколько отдельных вопросов. Кроме того, задавая подобные вопросы, стоит указать пример входных данных и то что вы хотите получить на выходе - это позволит тем кто отвечает на ваш вопрос протестировать свои решения

Comment: @MaxU Я исправил вопрос. Спасибо за подсказку

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю в каких точках вы хотите интерполировать... Поясните что такое `(b[i],0.0)`

Comment: Это сетка с 1 единственны значением. В итоге получается 2х мерный рисунок, так как data_2 в принципе величина постоянная, но только определенный промежуток времени

Comment: Пардон, я не смогу помочь если не понимаю задачу до конца... Совет: параметр `xi` у `scipy.interpolate.griddata()` может принимать 2D матрицу в качестве точек в кот. надо интерполировать. Т.е. задав туда все ваши точки вы можете интерполировать всё за __один__ вызов данной функции. Т.е. это будет "вектороизированное" решение без циклов