# Как выполнить апроксимацию dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Как выполнить апроксимацию функции? Есть пример в датафрейме. Можно перевести в список. Кто сталкивался.

Файл https://dropmefiles.com/K96n8

```
    function
1   240.9
2   241.18
3   241.166
4   241.2
5   241.47
6   241.165
7   241.3
8   241.38
9   241.255
10  241.17
11  241.1
12  241.1
13  241.17
14  240.95
15  240.48
16  240.69
...
```

Пример

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Аппроксимировать можно по-разному. Вы с какой целью интересуетесь? Полиномы Чебышева есть, например. Есть сплайны. Можно и просто линейной функцией аппроксимировать. Вопрос в том, как стоит задача, вы же сразу спрашиваете про средство, не обозначив задачу.

Comment: по картинке не очень то понятно что вы хотите сделать. Вы хотите аппроксимировать ступенчатой функцией? Если да то какие условия для этой функции?

Comment: А вы картинку вручную рисовали? Что означает вертикальная линия между первой и второй "полочками" слева на рисунке?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Даже не знаю чем тут можно аппроксимировать, ибо даже полиномы Чебышева большой степени как-то не очень себя ведут, когда их степень уже приближается к количеству точек по которым идёт аппроксимация. Но может вас это и устроит.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from numpy.polynomial.chebyshev import Chebyshev

df = pd.read_csv('p.csv')
df.columns = ['x','y']

plt.figure(figsize=(10,7));
for i in [2,4,8,16]:
    c = Chebyshev.fit(df.x, df.y, i)
    df[f'y{i}'] = c(df.x)
sns.lineplot(data=df.drop(columns='x'));
```

[image: полиномы Чебышева]

Comment: Ну и хорошо. Полиномы Чебышева вообще отличная тема. :)  Но надо учитывать, что когда степень аппроксимирующего полинома приближается к количеству точек, по которым идёт аппроксимация, то это уже то, что в машинном обучении называется "переобучение". Главное тут вовремя остановиться. )

Comment: Ну, например, можно начать с линейной регрессии https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html Даже обычная линейная регрессия уже тема богатая

Comment: @Анжелика, [вот еще несколько вариантов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/614584/211923)

Comment: @MaxU О, сплайны! )